# A concise way to define properties for MVVM data binding in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

Is there a concise way to define properties in a ViewModel for data binding in C# WPF? The following property definition is very verbose, especially when there are lots of properties:

```
private bool mSomeProperty;

public bool SomeProperty
{
    get { return this.mSomeProperty; }
    set
    {
        if (value != this.mSomeProperty)
        {
            this.mSomeProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SomeProperty"));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C#, I like to make a base class and put some helper methods on it. Then I make my ViewModels descend from it. This is from memory, but it's something like this:

```
public class Observable : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void SetProperty<T>(ref T backingField, T newValue,
        string propertyName)
    {
        if (Equals(backingField, newValue))
            return;
        backingField = newValue;
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And, in usage:

```
public class MyClass : Observable
{
    private bool m_someProperty;

    public bool SomeProperty
    {
        get { return m_someProperty; }
        set { SetProperty(ref m_someProperty, value, "SomeProperty"); }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is actually identical to one solution I've already implemented, but it still feels clunky to me. It is a step in the right direction though.

Comment: @emddudley - actually, his method of implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in the base class is a very important improvement over the code in your question.  If you use your code, and try to make a derived class, you can't raise the event of the base class from the derived class.  You pretty much have to make a NotifyPropertyChanged() method in your base class to make this work.

Answer (score 2):

You might find some ideas here:

**Implementing and usage of INotifyPropertyChanged**
https://github.com/jbe2277/waf/wiki/Implementing-and-usage-of-INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 1):

You could always use DependencyProperties and propdp your heart out...

Comment: I won't use DependencyProperties in a ViewModel. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291518/inotifypropertychanged-vs-dependencyproperty-in-viewmodel for more information.

Comment: Its really up to you.  The post you linked to doesn't give any good reasons for not using DP's other than they are more heavy weight than POCOs.  Unless you actually are experiencing issues using them prematurely optimizing them out of the equation is... premature optimization.  A project I'm working on right now has ~40 VM's and M's, all of which extend DP, and I haven't noticed the application running slowly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Delphi Prism language (Pascal-based .NET language), you just add the [`notify`](http://74.125.155.132/search?q=cache:GOLWXxhYg9QJ:omnie.no-ip.org/movies/CodeGear%2520RAD%2520Studio%25202009/Delphi%2520Prism/Wiki/EN/Notify_%28keyword%29.html+%22notify+keyword%22+delphi+prism&cd=10&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a) keyword, and the compiler automatically implements INotifyPropertyChanged and writes all the boilerplate code for you:

```
property SomeProperty: bool; notify;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you won't get the property declaration much smaller than that, at least not with "normal" ways. You could use an castle interceptor to take care of the event raisal.

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChanged;
    public void FirePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }

    public virtual string MyProperty { get; set; }
    public virtual string MyProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

The interceptor would need to fire the property changed event:

```
public class PropertyChangedInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        //Pseudo code
        if (invocation.Method is Property Setter)
        {
            Call FirePropertyChanged of invocation.InvocationTarget ;
        }
    }
}
```

You just need to make sure that your view model's properties are virtual and your view model is always an proxy and not the view model itself.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can consider [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.org/) which will allow you to decorate the property (which you could then redefine as an auto property) and inject into the setter the line that fires the NotifyPropertyChanged event.  An added benefit is you get rid of the string that is the same as the property name.

It's not ideal because you need that tool and it won't be immediately obvious if you are looking at the code later, but it definitely makes it neater.

I was hoping MSFT would add such an attribute to C# 4 but I guess we'll have to wait for C#5 if at all.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is very similar to Joe White's answer above, but the code is a little terser, and possibly a little more maintainable since the names of the properties don't have to be passed as a quoted string.

By using the **CallerMemberName** functionality, there are two ways to do this. One is to create an abstract class that contains the *IPropertyNotifyChanged* code and the other approach is to include the  *IPropertyNotifyChanged* support code in the actual class. I generally use both depending on the context.

Here is what the results look like when using an abstract class:

```
public abstract class PropertyNotifier: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged support code
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value,
        [CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
    {
        bool result = false;

        if (!Object.Equals(storage, value))
        {
            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }
    #endregion INotifyPropertyChanged support code
}
```

And in usage:

```
public interface IPerson
{
    String FirstName { get; set }
    String LastName { get; set }
}

public class Person : PropertyNotifier, IPerson
{
    private string _FirstName;
    private string _LastName;

    public String FirstName
    {
        get => _FirstName;
        set => SetProperty(ref _FirstName, value);
    }

    public String LastName
    {
        get => _LastName;
        set => SetProperty(ref _LastName, value);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!