# Implement INotifyPropertyChanged on DataContext in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged

When doing databinding does one have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on the datacontext in WPF?

Comment: This one has been answered on SO before [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291518/inotifypropertychanged-vs-dependencyproperty-in-viewmodel)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. If you don't intend for your object's properties to change, or you don't mind if the UI doesn't reflect those changes, there's no reason to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Further, if your object derives from [DependencyObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.aspx) and its properties are [dependency properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx), data binding will work without INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: but my object's properties do change and I do mind when my UI doesn't reflect those changes.  So which is better to use, INotifyPropertyChanged or dependency object?

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged is a bit simpler IMHO, and doesn't require you to derive from a certain class, so you have the option of keeping your own class hierarchy.

Comment: I agree.  INotifyPropertyChanged is simpler to implement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in a comparison between INotifyPropertyChanged and DependencyProperties you can find a good article [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/62158/DependencyProperties-or-INotifyPropertyChanged.aspx).
In general, if the object supports DependencyProperties, try to avoid INotifyPropertyChanged.