# How do I link (dependency) properties in my ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, mvvm

Simplified example:

I have an object that models a user.  Users have a first name and a last name.  The `UserViewModel` has a dependency property for my `Models.User` object.  In the declaration of the `UserView`'s xaml, I want to bind a couple of `TextBlocks` to the first and last name properties.

What is the correct way to do this?  Should I have readonly `DependencyProperties` for the name fields, and when the dependency property `User` is set, update them?  Can the name fields be regular C# properties instead?  Or, should I bind like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding User.FirstName}" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You typically will never use Dependency Properties in your ViewModel or Model classes.  You'll want to have your ViewModel implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) instead.

If you do that, you can bind using the syntax above.  (Though, if you want two-way binding to work appropriately, your "User" object will also need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged - otherwise, changes made in code to the user will not automatically reflect in the UI.)

Comment: I see that although I've worded it completely differently, this is somewhat covered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291518/inotifypropertychanged-vs-dependencyproperty-in-viewmodel.

So what you are saying is that User should be a POCO, and when User is set, then the readonly FirstName and LastName (POCO) fields are also set, and PropertyChanged is signalled for each?