# Dependency Property vs INotifyPropertyChanged in ViewModel for Windows 8 application

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, inotifypropertychanged, dependencyobject

I have created blank C#/XAML Windows 8 application. Add simple XAML code:

```
<Page
    x:Class="Blank.MainPage"
    IsTabStop="false"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <StackPanel
            Margin="0,150"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock
                x:Name="xTitle"
                Text="{Binding Title, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <Button Content="Click me!" Click="OnClick" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And the simple code in C# part:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage
    {
        private readonly ViewModel m_viewModel;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            m_viewModel = new ViewModel
            {
                Title = "Test1"
            };
            DataContext = m_viewModel;
        }

        private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            m_viewModel.Title = "Test2";
        }
    }
```

Now I want to implement `ViewModel`. I have two way:

1. Use [Dependency Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx)
2. Implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)

For first approach it is:

```
public class ViewModel : DependencyObject
    {
        public string Title
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(TitleProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(string)
            , typeof(ViewModel)
            , new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));
    }
```

For second it is:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string m_title;

        public string Title
        {
            get
            {
                return m_title;
            }
            set
            {
                m_title = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Title");
            }
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (null != PropertyChanged)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

I prefer the first way, because it allows use [coerce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx#animations) (Silverlight for web and for WP7 doesn't have [coerce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx#animations) functionality.. WinRT too.. but I'm still looking and hope) and looks more natural for me. But unfortunately, it works as [OneTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingmode.aspx) for the first approach.

Could anybody explain to me why MS abandon using [Dependency Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) for implementing view model?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551204/when-to-use-a-wpf-dependency-property-versus-inotifypropertychanged/3552550#3552550 this might help

Comment: @lukas I know about pros and cons. But way with dependency property doesn't work proper (only as `OneTime`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not be using a DependencyProperty in your ViewModel - you should only use them in your controls.  You will never want to bind one ViewModel to another, also ViewModels do not need to persist their values nor provide default values, nor provide property metadata.

You should only use INotifyPropertyChanged in your ViewModels.

Comment: Personally I do not agree. I'm always prefer to use DP in my View Models, since: a - it performs faster (no use of reflection) and b - its semantics says "this staff belongs to presentation layer". The current behavior of external DP in WinRT (e.g. "OneTime") I am considering as a bug. Would be nice to get some comment on this from Microsoft team.

Comment: I would disagree with you, check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx. "The purpose of dependency properties is to provide a way to compute the value of a property based on the value of other inputs. These other inputs might include system properties such as themes and user preference, just-in-time property determination mechanisms such as data binding and animations/storyboards, multiple-use templates such as resources and styles, or values known through parent-child relationships with other elements in the element tree"