# ObservableCollection dependency property not updating when add is called

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I am having some strange problems with my ObservableCollection. I am using .Net 4.0.

I have a viewmodel like this:

```
PoViewModel : DataViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<PoDetail> PoDetails { <omitting dp boiler code for ease> }

    public void Add()
    {
        this.PoDetails.Add(new PoDetail()); //<-- this is not getting detected in the wpf UI
    }
}
```

DataViewModelBase is a DependencyObject

I have this bit of test code that is verifying nothing is happening:

```
protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
    this.IsDirty = true;
    MessageBox.Show(e.Property.Name + " just changed");
}
```

What could be the problem? I am assuming I don't understand how ObservableCollections work but from everything I have read this should be working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need a dependency property on your viewModel?

Simply implementing [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) should be enough.

Also, you don't expect the property of name "PoDetails" to be updated when adding an element to the `ObservableCollection`. You should expect the `CollectionChanged` event of the `ObservableCollection` instance to be raised.

Comment: My view model has a dependency property on it because that is how I was taught to hook up view models to wpf ui's.

Comment: @PriceJones That generally not required. INotifyPropertyChanged is "better" IMO. See a great MVVM example here: http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/ See a discussion of INPC vs dependency object here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291518/inotifypropertychanged-vs-dependencyproperty-in-viewmodel