# When object changed my view don't in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, view, code-behind

Ok, so I have property `public Person ActualPerson { get; set; }` in my code-behind. I set `DataContext` like this: `this.DataContext = this;` .

In XAML I have bind `DataContext` in `StackPanel` like this: `DataContext="{Binding ActualPerson,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`. And in each `TextBlock`: `Text="{Binding Path=Name,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

My problem is, when I start my app I have properties form my object and all TextBlocks are filled with data, but when Person class object change, then view didn't refresh values. My Person class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. What I'm doing wrong? Should my UserControll class implement INotifyPropertyChanged rather then Person class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're not actually calling `PropertyChanged` for the `ActualPerson` object, so the binding on the `DataContext` won't be updated.

```
public Person ActualPerson
{
    get { return this.actualPerson; }
    set
    {
        if (this.actualPerson == value)
            return;

        this.actualPerson = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("ActualPerson");
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

EDIT:

It would help to see your ViewModel and code-behind to see how you're handling this. If, for example, you're setting the ActualPerson object that's defined on your `UserControl`, you may be better off using a `DependencyProperty`.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ActualPersonProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "ActualPerson", typeof (Person), typeof (MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(Person)));

public Person ActualPerson
{
    get { return (Person) GetValue(ActualPersonProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ActualPersonProperty, value); }
}
```

Comment: Also remember to specify the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: Ok, but my Person class implements INotifyPropertyChanged. So my code-behind class should implement that interface?

Comment: Well your binding needs to be notified somehow of a change.  Instead of using `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your code-behind, I would go with the suggestion I added in with my edit of using a `DependencyProperty` @ext

Comment: Option with `DependencyProperty` works, but how? And I want to know, `INotifyPropertyChanged` should be implemented in model class like mine (Person class)? Or Window / UserControl class?

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged should be implemented on any class that's used in bindings, either WPF bindings or in controls like a grid where you want it to know of property changes for each row.  In order to be able to use a DependencyProperty, you need to use a class that derives from `DependencyObject`, which rules out most classes aside from the code-behind.  You may want to take a look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291518/inotifypropertychanged-vs-dependencyproperty-in-viewmodel)