# Wpf usercontrol dependency Property Binding

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, dependency-properties

In my mainwindow I have got an UserControl, which ViewModel has got the Dependency Property "Message", I'm trying to bind the Dependency Property to an Property of the ViewModel of the Main Window, but actually it isn't Working, is there any soulution or is it genarally impossible?

Content of the Main Window:

```
    <local:MessageLayer>
        <local:MessageLayer.DataContext>
            <local:MessageBoxViewModel Message="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=DataContext.Message}"/>
        </local:MessageLayer.DataContext>
    </local:MessageLayer>
```

Comment: Simply use Path=Message instead of Path=DataContext.Message

Comment: That doesn't solves the Problem,
for both ways I got these output:
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Window', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=Message; DataItem=null; target element is 'MessageBoxViewModel' (HashCode=63995229); target property is 'Message' (type 'String')

Comment: @Sivasubramanian, no, because he also specified a RelativeSource

Comment: btw, using a DependencyObject as a ViewModel is quite unusual, and with good reasons. Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291518/inotifypropertychanged-vs-dependencyproperty-in-viewmodel

Comment: @ThomasLevesque alright, is there an other way to bind the Message of the MessageBoxViewModel to the Message Property of the MainWindow?
I think the Message Property of the M;essageBoxViewModel has to be an DependencyProperty

Comment: @CedricKrause, no, that's not necessary; you just need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. But anyway, that's probably not the cause of your problem. Have you tried to use ElementName instead of RelativeSource?

Comment: Yes I tried this before using the RelativeSource.
How could I solve this using an PropertyChanged, how should I set the Message of the Message layer

Comment: I simply could use the DataContext of the MainWindow for the MessageBoxLayer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View models should *not* have `DependencyProperty`s in them and should certainly *not* extend the `DependencyObject` class, because these are UI related classes. I'm sure that you, along with many others have been confused by Microsoft's terribly worded error below:

> A 'Binding' can only be set on a `DependencyProperty` of a `DependencyObject`.

This is really only referring to the UI element side of `Binding`s and *not* the data element side. For data binding data objects, we implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead, which provides similar property change notification functionality to `DependencyProperty`s.

So, had you set the `Window.DataContext` to an instance of a view model that implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`, with a property declared in it named `Message`, then your code would have worked just fine:

```
<local:MessageLayer>
    <local:MessageLayer.DataContext>
        <local:MessageBoxViewModel Message="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
            AncestorType=Window, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=DataContext.Message}"/>
    </local:MessageLayer.DataContext>
</local:MessageLayer>
```