# WPF How to refresh a user control

Tags: c#, wpf

I tried `UIElement.InvalidateVisual` but it didn't work. I read about this `INotifyPropertyChanged` but I don't know exactly how it is used, not to mention I'm talking about User Controls, it seems I need to use that `INotifyPropertyChanged` to all of the controls.

I'm having trouble refreshing combo boxes changes and data grid changes, what I did is to close and reopen the form but I don't want that approach because it seems sluggish in re-executing every user control constructors.

this is my code:

```
if (linkSource.ToString() == "BreedList.xaml")
{
    this.InvalidateVisual();
}
else if (linkSource.ToString() == "PetTypeList.xaml")
{
    this.InvalidateVisual();
}
else if (linkSource.ToString() == "IrritantList.xaml")
{
    this.InvalidateVisual();
}
```

Comment: Delete all your code and start reading [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx). There's no such thing as "refresh a UserControl" in WPF. There's proper XAML and DataBinding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This answer is an attempt to give you a peek into how WPF applications work, but I am *not* offering to teach you WPF... that is *your* job.

As @HighCore correctly pointed out, there is no `UserControl.Refresh` method. In a WPF Application (using MVVM), we create custom class objects called view models that contain the data and functionality that the `UserControl`s and/or `Window`s (called views) need to provide. They are paired by setting the view `DataContext` property to an instance of the relevant view model. There are several ways to do that... this is just one way:

```
public SomeView()
{
    ...
    DataContext = new SomeViewModel();
}
```

Now, all of the controls declared in `SomeView` have access to all of the (`public`) properties and `ICommand`s from the `SomeViewModel` class. We use them with data binding:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SomePropertyInSomeViewModel}" ... />
```

...

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollectionPropertyInSomeViewModel}" />
```

During initialisation of the `SomeViewModel` class, we might see something like this:

```
public SomeViewModel()
{
    SomeCollectionPropertyInSomeViewModel = SomeDataSource.GetSomeCollection();
}
```

This gets the data from any external data source and populates the `SomeCollectionPropertyInSomeViewModel` property. In turn, the `SomeCollectionPropertyInSomeViewModel` property provides the collection items for the `ListBox`. So finally, to answer your question, *How do we refresh the data?*, the answer is to call the methods that get the data again. So you could do something like this:

```
public void RefreshData()
{
    SomeCollectionPropertyInSomeViewModel = SomeDataSource.GetSomeCollection();
}
```

Ok, so here ends today's lesson. For any further questions, please refer to the proper Microsoft documentation on MSDN. For follow up information, please see the [Introduction to WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970268(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: I don't think that such a condescending tone is an appropriate one for an answer, regardless of the knowledge gap of the person asking.

Answer (score 1):

To add to previous answer: there are two ways to create "SomeViewModel". In both ways it should notify about a property change.

1) Use a DependencyObject. This is a standard WPF way, all UserControls are also DependencyObjects. Taken from here, read full explanation: http://wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html

```
    public class SomeViewModel : DependencyObject
    {
        // Dependency Property
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentTimeProperty =
             DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentTime", typeof(DateTime),
             typeof(SomeViewModel), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(DateTime.Now));

        // .NET Property wrapper
        public DateTime CurrentTime
        {
            get { return (DateTime)GetValue(CurrentTimeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CurrentTimeProperty, value); }
        }
    }
```

When CurrentTime changes everybody which is registered ( for example using {Binding CurrentTime} in XAML ) will get a notification and "Refresh"

2) Use INotifyPropertyChanged interface. Here's a small example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229614(v=vs.100).aspx

There are some differences between this approaches ( for example you can't create binding *to* INotifyPropertyChanged property ). Please read here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/62158/DependencyProperties-or-INotifyPropertyChanged
[INotifyPropertyChanged vs. DependencyProperty in ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291518/inotifypropertychanged-vs-dependencyproperty-in-viewmodel)

Good luck!