# WPF ItemsControl binding not updating when bound to an ObservableCollection in an object in the View Model

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, dependency-properties

Basically I have an object in my view model that contains an ObservableCollection of a custom object. My XAML's DataContext is set to my ViewModel, my ViewModel contains a 'Scratchdisk' object, and the Scratchdisk object contains an ObservableCollection of Frame objects. Both the Scratchdisk and the Collection are set up as DependencyProperties.

In short: `XAML --DataContext--> EditorViewModel --DependencyProperty--> Scratchdisk --DependencyProperty--> ObservableCollection<Frame>`

The Frame object has 3 standard properties: Index, Image, and ImageUrl.

I'm trying to bind to the ObservableCollection in my XAML using this code:

```
<ItemsControl DataContext="{Binding Source=ThumbnailScratchdisk}" ItemsSource="{Binding Frames, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ThumbnailTemplate}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></VirtualizingStackPanel>
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Where ThumbnailTemplate is defined in Window Resources as:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ThumbnailTemplate">
    <Image Width="128" Height="96" Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Theoretically, what should happen is, the Scratchdisk should receive filenames, create Frame objects, add them to the Collection, and then the binding should display them. The ObservableCollection is working and being populated, but the binding doesn't seen to be updating. All the updatable properties are set as DependencyProperties so the binding should update shouldn't it?

Links to the files:

[XAML](https://github.com/cbooth/Cutting-Room-Floor-XRF/blob/master/Cutting%20Room%20Floor/Views/MainWindow.xaml)

[ViewModel](https://github.com/cbooth/Cutting-Room-Floor-XRF/blob/master/Cutting%20Room%20Floor/ViewModels/EditorViewModel.cs)

[Scratchdisk](https://github.com/cbooth/Cutting-Room-Floor-XRF/blob/master/Cutting%20Room%20Floor/IO/Temporary/Scratchdisk.cs)

[Frame](https://github.com/cbooth/Cutting-Room-Floor-XRF/blob/master/Cutting%20Room%20Floor/IO/Video/Frame.cs)

Comment: Please post the viewmodel code which has observable collection. Please post the complete hierarchy of your top level datacontext. I feel your binding with the Frames object but your datacontext is viewmodel. You need to navigate to ViewModel.ScratchObject.Frames

Comment: @PiyushParashar I've linked the files at the bottom of the post, they're fairly big files so I didn't want to quote them in the question.

Comment: You need to notify the change of any properties in your `Frame`, e.g. `ImageUrl` to your View. You can test it by giving a default value of `ImageUrl` in the `Frame` class, if you can now see this default value, then you know the binding is working, just not updated when it changes in the VM.

Comment: Side comment: [don't use DependencyObject as VM base](http://stackoverflow.com/q/291518/1997232).

Comment: Please put some more effort in your question , your viewmodel with the observablecollection , where you update it , what ever 'ThumbnailScratchdisk' is and only relevant xaml. 

no one want's to dl your stuff

Comment: *my ViewModel contains a 'Scratchdisk' object, and the Scratchdisk object contains an ObservableCollection of Frame objects. Both the Scratchdisk and the Collection are set up as DependencyProperties*... we do *not* use `DependencyProperty`s in view models as they are UI elements... just use standard CLR type properties in your class.

Comment: @eranotzap I linked to the files because they're too long to quote in the question. Nowhere did I ask anyone to dl anything.

Comment: @Sheridan If I change the DP's to standard properties, will I still be able to two way bind to them?

Comment: Why you're using a `DependencyProperty` in your ViewModel? That seems unusual to me. A DP is basically just a property definition, and is typically used when the data for the property will be supplied by someplace else that this class won't have reference to. That said, it sounds like you're misunderstanding how the `DataContext` works a bit - it's the data item backing the control that the control's bindings use. I wrote a blog post on this for WPF beginners if you're interested: [What is this "DataContext" you speak of?](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/)

Comment: @CallumBooth, using CLR properties in a non UI class is practically the same as using `DependencyProperty`s in a UI class, but `DependencyProperty`s should only be used in UI classes.

Comment: @Rachel Thanks for that link! I think I must've got confused when reading about DependencyProperties for the first time. I assumed that any property that's being bound to needs to be a DP, but obviously this isn't the case presumably.

Comment: @CallumBooth It is true that if you are going to be binding a property in XAML, it has to be a DependencyProperty. For example, `TextBox.Text` has to be a DependencyProperty so we can set it to a binding. This allows WPF's binding system to get and set the property using the property definition defined for it. However the value you are binding *to* does not need to be a DP. That can be any regular public property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the binding of the `DataContext` of your `ItemsControl`.
You're setting it to `"{Binding Source=ThumbnailScratchdisk}"`, but what you (presumably) want is to set it to just `"{Binding ThumbnailScratchdisk}"`.

The `DataContext` of the page is already an instance of `EditorViewModel`, and you want the `DataContext` for the `ItemsControl` to bind to the property `ThumbnailScratchdisk` of that viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

Trying changing the binding path in XAML to `ThumbnailScratchdisk.Frames`

Comment: Sorry, this didn't work. I thought this would've been implied though since the ItemsControl's DataContext was set to ThumbnailScratchdisk

Comment: Yes I realized that as soon I posted it :( I can not find SetValue method in ScratchObject class. Where is it and what is the code?